# Write R data frame to Hadoop Hive

Tags: r, hadoop, rodbc, rhadoop

I want to write a data frame in R to a new table in Hadoop Hive. I'm using sqlSave() in the RODBC package as shown below. The table structure is created in Hadoop, but I get an error before any data is inserted into the table. Error message is included below. Any suggestions on how to write a data frame in R to a new table in Hadoop?

**CODE**

```
column_1 = c("a","b","c")

column_2 = c("d","e","f")

column_3 = c("g","h","i")

test.df = data.frame(column_1,column_2,column_3)

columnTypes <- list(column_1='varchar(255)',
                    column_2='varchar(255)',
                    column_3='varchar(255)')

sqlSave(dbConn, test.df, 'db.tablename', verbose=T, append=T, rownames = F, fast = F, varTypes = columnTypes)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Query: CREATE TABLE db.tablename  ("column_1" varchar(255), "column_2" varchar(255), "column_3" varchar(255))
Query: INSERT INTO db.tablename ( "column_1", "column_2", "column_3" ) VALUES ( 'a', 'd', 'g' )
Error in sqlSave(dbConn, test.df, "db.tablename", verbose = T,  : 
[Microsoft][HiveODBC] (55) Insert operation is not support for table: HIVE.db.tablename
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'INSERT INTO db.tablename ( "column_1", "column_2", "column_3" ) VALUES ( 'a', 'd', 'g' )'
```

Comment: So you thought Hive was a transactional database, like MySQL or Oracle? Not really. Your best option is to create an *EXTERNAL TABLE* mapped on a HDFS directory containing CSV files, then generate these files with `rhdfs`.

Comment: Actually there *is* a way to manage a transactional table in Hive, but the setup requires an experienced Hadoop admin and the result is neither pretty nor performant.

Answer (score 1):

Set up your connection like this:

```
library(odbc)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                  Driver    ="HIVE",
                  Host      = "myhadoopurl.com",
                  Port      = "8443",
                  Schema    = "my_schema_db_name",            
                  HttpPath  = "gateway/default/hive",   
                  AuthMech  = "3",
                  HiveServerType  = "2",
                  ThriftTransport = "2",
                  UID = my_user_name,
                  PWD = my_pw)

#Got an error here, that Hive doesn't like the iris . in the column names so...
names(iris)<-gsub("\\.","_",names(iris))

DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "my_schema_db_name.iris", iris)
```

I got some permission denied errors on this, which were misleading. After tinkering with the schema name on the connection settings and the dbWriteTable function it worked. To append:

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "my_schema_db_name.iris", iris, append=TRUE)
```

It did not work, if I left the connection schema blank and used the default schema for Hive to connect, that's where I got permission errors.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same problem, I need users from our team to start using Hive and all most of them are Hive users. Here's what I have done so far:
 - Create a custom function in R to automatically generate create table statement for the new hive table
 - Do conversion of data types in preparation to hive, convert factors to character, arrange date formats
 - Generate text file for loading to hive
 - Move text file to Hadoop(MapR in my case) using rhdfs, either on your desired location (external table) or load to hive warehouse.

Hope someone has better solution but for me this works. Working on automating the process by creating R package but I'm far from done.